# Substring certain parts of text from an NSString

Tags: iphone, parsing, rss, nsstring, substring

I am working at revamping some previous blog apps.  I parse the XML, but so far, when a table view cell is clicked, I just have it open the URL for the article that was clicked by the user.  This is beginning to get frowned upon by Apple, and I need to change it anyways, so I can gain some more options with display.  The entire article is displayed with this tag:

```
<content:encoded>
```

I am able to get the data from within this tag, but there are a couple issues.  It always starts off with

```
<![CDATA[<p>
```

And ends with

```
</p>]]>
```

As you can see, it also contains not true text but code, such as

```
<p> and </p> and aren&#8217;t &#8220
```

Any suggestions for how I can parse this to remove the beginning and ends of the string, and convert to all true text that I can load in my view?

Comment: Have you tried using NSXMLParser?

Comment: @CemalEker   I've had some different people suggest NSXML Parser, but didn't give me any ideas as to what I can do with the string of this text to format it.

Comment: NSXMLParser automatically clears appended CDATA and decodes html entities like &#8217; to their respective unicode chars. You should maybe remove html tags like <p> with string replace, after parsing XML file with NSXMLParser. That would clearly simplify the proccess here.

Comment: @CemalEker So would I need to change the current method of xml parsing I am doing right now, or could I use an nsxml parser to just parse the nsstring that the other parsing had done?  I like everything else in my current setup, that's why I am nervous if I have to change it all.

Comment: You could not use NSXMLParser over a parsed string. You should provide a valid XML to NSXMLParser to achieve desired functionality. Do you currently use any framework or tool to parse XML? If so what's it?

Comment: @CemalEker I use GDataXMLElement

Comment: I don't know if you can decode xml entities with GDataXMLParser. But you can still use NSString's `rangeOfString:` selector to find CDATA blocks. For example: `[data rangeOfString:@"<![CDATA[<p>"]`. And use `deleteCharactersInRange:` selector to delete found string from your data.